# If you replaced jetfuel with hydrogen could the aircraft engine work on hydrogen?

Tags: jet-engine, fuel

I know that hydrogen has a reaction with oxygen like with jet fuel, but could the engine run on hydrogen.

Comment: While it's certainly possible to do so (jet engines will run on almost anything that burns - see the answer on the duplicate) hydrogen has [a few disadvantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster) which make it less than attractive as an aviation fuel.

Comment: Also, aside from its tendency to combust at inopportune times, hydrogen is a pain to store. It either has to be compressed to very high pressures or take up **a lot** of space. [Or both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_external_tank).

Comment: @voretaq7 If this is a duplicate, the other question should be edited to be more generic.

Comment: @digitgopher A question need not be an ***exact*** duplicate to be closed as such. See http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates for more information.

Comment: Your fuel tank will get MUCH bigger and heavier. Hydrogen has great energy density by mass (eg kWh/kg)...until you contain it. To store H2 at STP takes a LOT of volume. Liquid H2 (cryo storage) isn't practical for general use, and even as a liquid H2 has far worse volumetric energy density than petrofuels. High pressure gas storage means massy containers with thick walls and the volumetric density is far worse than for liquid H2. See http://www.tinaja.com/glib/energfun.pdf - table on p.2. Funnily enough, a liter of petrofuel has more H2 in it than a liter of liquid H2.